# How to get the value of geolocation in a javascript function

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have the following function which takes two values: latitude and longitude:

```
    getgps(latitude , longitude);
```

and I need for this to get the data from the geolocation function:

```
 <script>

function getLocation() {
   if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
   }
}
function showPosition(position) {
  var x = position.coords.latitude;
  var y = position.coords.longitude; 
 getgps(x , y);

}
  </script>
```

but it is not working

The good script

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) { 
 findGps(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude); });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**NOTE:** when you start your code, in browser top left corner it showing popup for asking for allow access your location. allow it. if you allow, it will show you location otherwise it wont able to find your location.

if i understand your problem correct. this is working code what you want to achieve. refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

```
Working fiddle: `https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/`

Hope it will help you.
```

Comment: the code is simply navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
  findGps(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
});

Comment: can you please explain what is your basic question

Answer (score 0):

you have to call the navigator.geolocation function, that have success and error callbacks functions.

Try to call your gepgps function in the success callback, like this :

```
        var onGeoSuccess = function(position) {                
            getgps(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude)
        };

        function onGeoError(error) {
            alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
                'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onGeoSuccess, onGeoError);
```